# Why cannot define a static vector in rust?

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```rust
struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    static static_value: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
}

fn main() {
    for elem in MyStruct::static_value {
        println!("{}", elem);
    }
}
```

And the compiler gives an error:

```
error: associated `static` items are not allowed
 --> test.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     static static_value: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Though in this case, I can simply replace the `Vec<i32>` with an integer array, still I would like to know why the rust compiler will prohibit such code and if there is any ways I can define a static vector.

Comment: A vector is heap-allocated, so it cannot be `static`, i.e. baked into the executable. The classic idiom is to use `lazy_static`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=821dbece992700b77770a28590561590

Comment: Read [this Rust koan](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-koans/2408/2) and come back.  You may be enlightened.

Comment: Note that this error is not related to `Vec` specifically - it would fire even if the type of item was `i32` or other `const`-constructible value, so the title and the question itself are technically asking different things. You might want to unify them, to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is the purpose of a static vector? Can you use a const array instead? `const STATIC_VALUE: [i32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is practically a constant vector.
The main difference ( in terms of usability ) between a vector and an array is the vectors ability to have a dynamic size which of course would be lost if it were constant.

`static ARR: [i32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];`

should be exactly what you are looking for.

As user4815162342 said  "A vector is heap-allocated, so it cannot be static, i.e. baked into the executable."

This is the low level reason why a static vector is not possible.